# Enviar SMS via Php

Tags: php, sms, serial

Estava usando um gateway para envio de sms (**nowsms**) porém o período de avaliação encerrou e fui comprar a licensa, U$995 para enviar 12 sms por minuto, não achei viável.

Pesquisando encontrei um classe Php-Serial (https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial) porém não consigo enviar nada para o modem, sempre dá erro ao indicar o `baud rate`.

Alguém já fez algo parecido que possa me ajudar ?

Comment: Voce está usando linux? Se sim, tenta primeiro falar com o modem via minicom. minicom -s para configurar a porta. Sugiro BAUD RATE 9600 8N1 para falar com o modem. Se for um modem USB, tu vai precisar instalar um modulo do kernel chamado usbserial .

Comment: Infelizmente a empresa para qual estou prestando utiliza servidor windows. Ainda estou quebrando a cabeça para solucionar isto. Agradecido de toda forma :)

Comment: Uma opção é o Twilio SMS. Custa US$ 0,06 por mensagem para o Brasil e US$ 0,04 para Portugal. A API deles é bem simples. Se não for enviar muitos SMS, pode valer a pena. https://www.twilio.com

Comment: Já que falaram do Twilio, podes usar o PagueVeloz. Funciona muito bem e o preço fica muito abaixo do Twilio principalmente por causa da cotação do dólar e do IOF da transação internacional. API toda REST, e se cadastrando lá já ganha 30 SMS pra testar o serviço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O mensagem `baud rate` me parece apenas parte do erro, você deve ser mais especifico de qual erro ocorre.

Um exemplo que você pode usar para detectar a falha é:

1. Abrir o CMD
2. Verificar qual porta o seu modem usa (vamos supor que seja COM17)
3. Executar o comando pelo CMD:

   ```
   mode COM17 xon=on BAUD=9600
   ```

   Se a porta fosse COM20 então o comando seria:

   ```
   mode COM20 xon=on BAUD=9600
   ```

Com isto você poderá detectar o erro (se o modem tem suporte por exemplo)

### Como verificar qual porta do dispositivo (modem)

1. Abra o executar ou cmd
2. Digite `%SystemRoot%\system32\control.exe` ou abra o painel de controle
3. Vá até "gerenciador de drivers"
4. Clique na aba Detalhes, deve aparecer o nome e em seguida a porta, por exemplo `Modem (COM 17)`

No caso se a porta for 17 o script deve ficar algo como:

```
<?php
include 'PhpSerial.php';

$serial = new PhpSerial;

$serial->deviceSet('COM17');
...
```