# Em PHP existe suporte à Bluetooth?

Tags: php, api, aplicação-web, bluetooth

Se não, em geral (web) existe suporte à bluetooth? Existe algum meio de fazer a comunicação entre *PORT COM* (Bluetooth) para web?

Comment: seria mais fácil alguém te dar uma resposta para seu problema se souber o que você pretende fazer. Mas em termos gerais você consegue ler as portas COM através com PHP basicamente como um middleware, como por exemplo: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/17926.html

Comment: Sendo mais especifico, diretamente desejo usar/instanciar um controlador Bluetooth via WEB, uma pagina web que o usuário faça controle do dispositivo bluetooth. Por exemplo em C# faço esse controle referenciando a bibliote 32feet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O controle do Bluetooth só vai funcionar no servidor (no lado do servidor), ou seja se o usuário acessar do computador dele ele só vai conseguir enviar "comandos", mas a máquina que vai estar executando isto é o servidor.

Note que se um usuário acessar o Bluetooh, este mesmo ficará ocupado e outros usuários não poderão acessar até que o primeiro termine o processo.

Provavelmente a classe https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial usada nesta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68734/3635) deve ter o mesmo objetivo.

### Windows:

1. Abra o executar ou cmd
2. Digite `%SystemRoot%\system32\control.exe` ou abra o painel de controle
3. Vá até "gerenciador de dispositivos"
4. Procure por "Bluetooth radios" (algo semelhante)
5. Selecione o dispositivo Bluetooth desejado com o botão direito do mouse e vá até propriedades
6. Clique na aba Detalhes, deve aparecer o nome e em seguida a porta, por exemplo `Bluetooh (COM 17)`

### Linux

No linux o dispositivo deve está como `/dev/rfcomm0`

### Usando

O script php deve ficar assim:

```
<?php
include 'PhpSerial.php';

$serial = new PhpSerial;
$serial->deviceSet('/dev/rfcomm0'); # No windows deve ser deviceSet('COM17')
```

Agora se você quiser enviar do bluetooth do computador do visitante, será necessário uma tecnologia como [java](/questions/tagged/java)