# Ler dados da porta serial com PHP

Tags: php, serial

minha situação é a seguinte:

Tenho varias balanças conectados no servidor, cada balança se conecta por uma porta serial, atualmente estou usando a porta COM5 (já tentei com outras maiores e menores).
Essas balanças enviam uma string constante pela porta serial (contendo o peso atual mostrado no visor da mesma).
Testei com codigos java é funcionou de boa, menos com o PHP.

segue alguns codigos já utilizados por mim:

```
$port = fopen('COM5', 'w'); //tente com r e r+ e nada
sleep(2);
echo fgets($port);
fclose($port);
```

utilizando o codigo acima o ele trava a porta COM5 e so retorna apos reiniciar o servico do apache (PHP).

com a extencao do com_dotnet.dll habilitada no php tambem, tive o seguinte erro.

```
$serial = new DOTNET('System', 'System.IO.Ports.SerialPort');
$serial->PortName = 'COM5';
$serial->Open();
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: Failed to instantiate .Net object [CreateInstance] [0x80070002] The system cannot find the file specified. in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(2): dotnet->dotnet('System', 'System.IO.Ports...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 2

Sei que enviar informacoes pela porta serial para um Arduino ele envia de boa, cheguei a testar tambem, o problema ocorre na leitura da mesma.
qualquer informacoes e bem vinda :(

Comment: Pode a classe PhpSerial, veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70993/3635 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69562/3635

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resolvido com o codigo:

```
$port = fopen('COM5', 'r+b');
sleep(1);
echo fgets($port);
fclose($port);
```